# Remote Desktop Services on Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

Is it possible to upgrade *just* Remote Desktop Services in Windows 2008, SP1?

Here's my take on it so far:

I know about WIN 2K8 R2 but upgrading to that is not an option (yet). I would like to take advantage of the multiple monitor support (not what you get with the '/span' option).

I tried looking for hotfix or resource packs but couldn't find one that allows me to upgrade just the Remote Desktop services. I have a feeling there is more to it a core OS level than just upgrading to RDS but not sure about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new features in Remote Desktop Services in Windows Server 2008 R2 aren't available as any kind of "add-on" to Windows Server 2008. Rarely does Microsoft "backport" new features to older operating systems (and sometimes, when they say they're going to, they end up not... I'm talking to you, promised SSTP client for Windows XP.)

Comment: I was thinking more like a Terminal Services pack in the old days. My guess is the new RDS relies heavily on RemoteFX which relies heavily on the new kernel and that's why it could not be backported. Could you confirm/reject my postulate?